# Как сделать регистрацию на vkbottle (& telebot) на aiosqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, telebot, бот, vkbottle

Я установил Aiosqlite

> pip install aiosqlite

Но ***не знаю*** как сделать регистрацию в боте под модулем vkbottle

P.s при желании можно telebot, если нету примеров на vkbottle

P.s.s. мне не нужен sqlite

Спасибо

Comment: Что по вашему означает регистрация в боте?

Comment: mironovmeow, для меня значит так. Когда человек пишет любую команду (или слово) то бот проверят есть он в базе, если нет то он создаёт в бд пользователя.

Comment: А до этого у вас была какая-то регистрация? Может, не знаю, на sqlite или просто в словаре? Трудности именно с aiosqlite или в целом не знаете как сделать регистрацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел способ как это сделать, надеюсь это поможет и другим

````py
# Запуск бота
print("Hello WOrld")
# Импорты
import asyncio
import vkbottle
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle import Keyboard, KeyboardButtonColor, Text, OpenLink, Location, EMPTY_KEYBOARD, template_gen, TemplateElement
import aiosqlite
import config

# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = Bot(config.VK_TOKEN)

# Создаем подключение к базе данных SQLite
async def create_connection():
    connection = await aiosqlite.connect("users.db")
    return connection

# Создаем таблицу пользователей
async def create_table(connection):
    async with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute(
            """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id INTEGER,
                username TEXT
            )
            """
        )

# Добавляем пользователя в базу данных
async def add_user(user_id: int, username: str, connection):
    async with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO users (user_id, username)
            VALUES (?, ?)
            """,
            (user_id, username)
        )
        await connection.commit()

# Обрабатываем команду /start
@bot.on.message(text="/start")
async def handle_start_command(message: Message):
    # Получаем информацию о пользователе
    user_id = message.from_id
    username = f"{message.from_id.first_name} {message.from_id.last_name}"
    
    # Создаем подключение к базе данных SQLite
    async with create_connection() as connection:
        # Создаем таблицу пользователей, если ее нет
        await create_table(connection)

        # Добавляем пользователя в базу данных
        await add_user(user_id, username, connection)

    # Отправляем приветственное сообщение
    await message.answer("Привет! Вы были зарегистрированы в нашей базе данных.")

# Запускаем бота
async def main():
    await bot.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())```
````

Comment: Как я понимаю, если пользователь будет писать `/start`, его будет постоянно _регистрировать_ (будет постоянно вызываться `add_user(...)`). Выглядит не очень надёжно...

Comment: Соглашусь, ведь я делаю первый раз

Answer (score 0):

Данную задачу необходимо реализовать самостоятельно, в вышеуказанных библиотеках (vkbottle / telebot), насколько мне известно, нет такой возможности *"из коробки"*.

У *vkbottle* есть [state-dispenser](https://vkbottle.github.io/vkbottle/high-level/handling/state-dispenser/), позволяет хранить состояние пользователя внутри программы. Есть [middleware](https://vkbottle.github.io/vkbottle/high-level/handling/middleware/), который позволяет проверять/изменять/дополнять ответ от сервера до того, как он попадает в хендлеры (или обрабатывает работу хендлеров). Есть [примеры кода](https://github.com/vkbottle/vkbottle/tree/master/examples/high-level), где используются все возможности данной библиотеки. Всё это поможет *сделать регистрацию* именно так, как это вам необходимо.